# Is there a refresh intervall for the local group policy?

Tags: group-policy

As the title says, is there a (background) refresh intervall for the **local** group policy? How often does it get applied? Once at Startup/Login? Coudn't find anything on Technet...

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Local Group Policy editor to configure local policies, they are immediately applied and logically don't need any kind of refresh or update interval.

Comment: Some policy settings are only applied at Startup (Computer) or Logon (User.)  There are also policies related to Desktop and/or Explorer that only take effect if Explorer is restarted (which happens at Logon too.)  I think Microsoft usually refers to that behavior as "Foreground" policy processing vs. background.  So your experience will depend on the specific setting.  In addition there are some security settings that affect network sessions and will only take affect with new sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Once the local group policies are in place, I believe they follow the same refresh interval as Site/Domain/OU ones, which is at startup/logon and then every 90 minutes.

The difference between local and network GPOs is the reach of them, not their settings or actions. Keep in mind, though, that certain GPOs are not applied automatically while the user is logged in to account for the likelihood of them interfering with programs or processes that are already running.
You should assume that they're applied only at startup (for computer GPOs) or logon (for user GPOs) for this reason. Unless, of course, you've scripted an update to include the command of gpupdate /force

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have created to scripts to test this. One is bound to the computer startup the other to the user logon via local group policy. both scripts basically just write a timestamp to a file. the result shows this scripts only get executed once!

Comment: If you haven't changed a group policy, it won't update/execute. If a policy is already executed on the machine/user, it doesn't need to do so again. All it needs to do is check for changes to the list.  If you want to see the log of when it's checked, you can see the "quick view" in Event Viewer under Windows Logs > System, and it will have the source of GroupPolicy (Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy). If you want to see the full log of checks/changes/updates, it's in Event Viewer > Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > GroupPolicy > Operational.